# How to install Foreman on Centos 6?

Tags: centos6, foreman

**Attempt**

According to [this documentation](http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.1/quickstart_guide.html), **Puppet** should be installed before installing **Foreman**.

*Puppet*

```
sudo rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6.4/products/x86_64/puppetlabs-release-6-11.noarch.rpm
sudo yum -y install puppet

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ puppet --version
3.7.1
```

*Foreman*

```
sudo yum -y install http://yum.theforeman.org/releases/1.1/el6/x86_64/foreman-release.rpm
sudo yum -y install foreman-installer
```

**Result**

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rubygem-apipie-bindings-0.0.8-4.el6.noarch (foreman)
           Requires: rubygem(mime-types) < 2.0.0
Error: Package: rubygem-rest-client-1.6.7-2.el6.noarch (foreman)
           Requires: rubygem(mime-types) >= 1.16
Error: Package: rubygem-apipie-bindings-0.0.8-4.el6.noarch (foreman)
           Requires: rubygem(fastercsv)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

---

**Attempt Two**

Checking the error message, the idea was to try to fix the dependency issues by trying to install the following packages:

```
rubygem mime-types < 2.0.0
rubygem mime-types >= 1.16
rubygem fastercsv
```

by issuing the following commands:

```
sudo gem install mime-types -v 1.25.1
sudo gem install gem install fastercsv
```

**Result Two**

*mime-types*

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo gem install mime-types -v 1.25.1
Successfully installed mime-types-1.25.1
1 gem installed
```

*fastercsv*

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo gem install gem install fastercsv
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'gem' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'install' (>= 0) in any repository
Successfully installed fastercsv-1.5.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for fastercsv-1.5.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for fastercsv-1.5.5...
```

*Foreman*

```
sudo yum -y install foreman-installer
```

Although the missing packages were installed using `gem install` the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to install and enable the EPEL repository. Do that, and then try the Foreman installation again.

Comment: Issuing the [following commands](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/install-epel-and-additional-repositories-on-centos-and-red-hat) `wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm` && `sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm` && installing foreman again solves the issue. (+1) Thank you.

Comment: Installing foreman, i.e., `sudo yum -y install foreman-installer` && `sudo foreman-installer`

Comment: Hey, even after enabling this I am getting same error. CentOS6.7, puppet version 3.8.2